# Using GetFunctionInfo to get the name of a function from a FunctionID

Tags: c++, .net, profiling, clr-profiling-api, imetadataimport

I am writing a CLR profiler using the `ICorProfilerInfo` interface.

When using `SetEnterLeaveFunctionHooks`, the callback methods are passed a `FunctionID`.

How do I get the metadata (I am after the name in particular), of a function given this `FunctionID`?

An MSDN article suggests that the first call should be to `GetFunctionInfo`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getfunctioninfo-method) for this function states:

> The profiler code can call ICorProfilerInfo::GetModuleMetaData to obtain a metadata interface for a given module. The metadata token that is returned to the location referenced by pToken can then be used to access the metadata for the function.

It does not elaborate on the last sentence ('the metadata token ... can be used to access metadata for the function').
How does this work?

So far, I am doing the following:

```
void MyProfiler::EnterMethod(FunctionID functionID)
{
    ClassID classId = 0;
    ModuleID moduleId = 0;
    mdToken metaDataToken = 0;
    IMetaDataImport* metaDataImport = NULL;

    // (m_info is ICorProfilerInfo3)
    m_info->GetFunctionInfo(functionID, &classId, &moduleId, &metaDataToken);
    m_info->GetModuleMetaData(moduleId, ofRead, IID_IMetaDataImport, (IUnknown**)&metaDataImport);

    // What goes here?
}
```

I have tried to call `GetTypeRefProps` like this:

```
    mdToken ptkResolutionScope;
    WCHAR szName[1024];
    ULONG cchName = 1024;
    ULONG pchName;

    HRESULT result = MetaDataImport->GetTypeRefProps(pToken, &ptkResolutionScope, szName, cchName, &pchName);
```

The final call returns `S_FALSE`, and does not populate `szName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetTypeRefProps` is only applicable when your token is a TypeRef token, `GetFunctionInfo` will give you a MethodDef token which requires you to use the [`GetMethodProps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataimport-getmethodprops-method) method.

```
metaDataImport->GetMethodProps(metaDataToken, NULL, szName, cchName, &pchName, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```